# Assembly 8086 string to number conversion

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to convert given string to its numeric value in decimal, "123" -> 123
but for some reason, I get 0 for every number I enter and I don't know why. Variable
apob is my string and bx should store result of the conversion.
What is causing my `bx` register to be equal to 0?

```
MOV si, 2
MOV ax, 10
XOR bx, bx
wartosc1:
MOV ax, 10
MOV dl, [apob+si]
CMP dl, 13
JE  end         
SUB dl, 48
INC si
MUL bx
MOV bx, ax
ADD bx, dx
JMP wartosc1
```

Comment: `si` is initialized to `2` and then incremented. If `apob` is really your string then that makes no sense. `mul bx` destroys `dx` and hence your current digit. Comment your code and use a debugger. Also, `dh` seems to be uninitialized.

Comment: I mean apob is an array defined in this specific way for INT 21h, AH 10 instruction.   apob db 6
  db 0
  TIMES 7 db '$' 
si is initialized to 2 because this is where my characters start in this array. And it is incremented each time to get new character until dl becomes 13 (enter). I believe MUL bx is 16 bit multiplication so its result is stored in DX:AX but since my result is small it will be stored in AX. Oh wait, so this will make DX = 0 and therefore DL = 0. So it seems this must be the problem. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
xor bx,bx
lea si,apob


wartosc1:
xor dx,dx
MOV dl, [si]
CMP dl,'$'
JE  endpr         
SUB dl, 48
push dx


mov ax,10
MUL bx
MOV bx, ax

pop dx

ADD bx, dx

INC si

JMP wartosc1
```

Your answer will be stored in bx

Comment: You could use CX instead of having to save/restore DX around MUL.

Comment: If you closely look at the OP's code and comments, you'll see that the text digits start at *apob + 2*.